# Vb.net How can I sleep between multiple tasks in a sub

Tags: vb.net, sleep

*Figured my previous attempt in doing this question was too opinion based, so I'll be more specific.*

**Intro:**

I'm trying to best way possible sleep inbetween multiple "tasks" within a private sub, but my attempts so far have failed me.

I have 9 "tasks" being triggered by a timer `timermain` and a progressbar `pbmain` that are working together. At `pbmain.value 10` task `1` is being triggered, at `pbmain.value 20` task `2` is being triggered and this goes all the way up to pbmain.value 100 and at that point it sets value to 1 and then this whole process loops over and over.

The problem is that this way is not very accurate because some of the tasks take more time than the others, so I'd much rather like to somehow sleep/pause/wait a second or so between each task than use progressbar value.

This is what it looks like

```
Private Sub TimerMain_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TimerMain.Tick

pbMain.Increment(1)
                                     'Channel 1
     If cbc1.Checked = True Then
        If pbMain.Value = 10 Then
            Try
                Dim fileTotal As Integer
                For Each item As String In lbChannel1.Items
                    fileTotal += My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(item.ToString, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, (tbExt1.Text)).Count
                Next
                tbCount1.Text = String.Format("{0}", fileTotal.ToString)
            Catch ex As Exception
                lbErrors.Items.Add(String.Concat(TimeOfDay & " Error 001: ", ex.Message)) 'Error output

            End Try
        End If
    End If
                                      'Channel 2
    '... same as above. Then channel 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9...
```

To clarify what this does and the whole purpose:
I have so called channels in my form. Each channel is a listbox with items that are paths like \server\share\folder. The code above counts files in those folders if checkbox for that specific channel is checked and gives number output to a textbox `tbcount1-9`. So yes, the application is monitoring files going in and out of specified folders.

**My goal:**

`Do task 1` **->** `Complete task 1 and wait one second` **->** `Move to task 2` **->** repeat this all the way to task 9 and then loop

**I've tried:**

- `Perform step`. Did not work well because it looped too fast and fast out of control. I removed pbmain.increment and used performstep between each task.
- `Thread.sleep`. This caused the whole application to sleep for given amout of time instead .
- `Progressbar marquee mode`. I tried, but couldn't figure out how to make it work like my goal.

**My question:**

How can I complete my goal using something else than progressbar value with a timer...?

---

***Update***

*Alexander's comment answered my question*

Comment: Why are the tasks triggered by a progress bar value? Have you thought about having the tasks send completed-events, so that follow-up tasks can be triggered?

Comment: Thats the thing. I don't want it to be triggered by progress bar value, but thats the only way I could make this work with my knownledge. When you ask that question, it sounds to me like its exactly what I'm looking for, but I simply don't know how to pull it off.

Comment: What are the tasks supposed to do, and why is one dependent from the other?

Comment: Well I have 9 channels. Each channel is basically a listbox with a few paths like for example \\server\share\folderA. So task one counts all the files in channel 1. Same goes for channel 2-9 and task 2-9. To sum up; they are all similar, but checkboxes choose whether if they should be counted or not. So all the tasks are basically similar, but I want to count them seperatly for a few reasons.

Comment: And are they counted once, or in intervals as long as the checkbox is on?

Comment: In intervals. The users will be able to turn on and off automatician and also set the timermain.interval to whatever they'd like. So yes, in intervals and its looping forever basically. One checkbox for each channel `cbc1-9`

Comment: Well then first, write your task code so that it can be reused (via parameters for example). "Never write the same code twice!" Then, in this case, give each file list its own timer, and let each task run in it's own thread when it is triggered. One task instance should not care if another instance is still working or not.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right track, Alexander. I think that is exactly what I should do to make this run properly. Though I fear I'll stumble upon a bunch (literally) of issues and question since this is a little bit out of my comfortable zone, but for sure I'll do my very best.

Comment: Insert random quote about life and learning here. Your response is just what I was hoping for. Good luck, happy coding!

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your time taken helping me out.

Answer (score 3):

You can try with `Asnyc/Await` [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)
Since your task are working with IO - `async/await` will be best approach.
Starting new thread only for waiting result from IO is waste of resources(threads).

```
Private Async Function ExecuteAllAsync() As Task
    While True
        Await ExecuteTasksAsync()
    End while
End Function


Private Async Function ExecuteTasksAsync() As Task
    Dim task1 As Task = ExecuteTaskNumberOneAsync()
    Await Task.Delay(1000)
    Dim task2 As Task = ExecuteTaskNumberTwoAsync()
    Await Task.Delay(1000)
    '... and so on
    'Then wait for all results
    Await Task.WhenAll({task1, task2, ...})
End Function
```

Here is only an idea - of course code above can/must be refactored to "usable" way

Comment: Thanks for your input, Fabio. I'll give it a try soon and get back to you with results.

Comment: You're starting something asynchronous, then wait for it to finish, make a pause, then start the next something asynchronous and wait for it to finish. 
Why asynch in the first place?

Comment: Exactly what OP want. _Do task 1 -> Complete task 1 and wait one second -> Move to task 2_

Answer (score 1):

Are you just looking for a simple 1 second delay? If so.

```
Dim Current_Time as Date=Now
While DateAdd(DateInterval.Second, 1, Current_Time)>Now

End While
```

Now returns the current Date and Time
So I guess your flow would be
Task1->
Delay 1 Sec->
Task 2